# Separate strings and make a group from cell array

Tags: string, matlab, text-processing, cell-array

```
Cell_in = {'a1','b1','b3','c3','c1','d3'};  % something like this

Cell_out = {'a1','b1','c1'; 
       'b3','c3','d3';...
       }
```

And so on, how can this be done?

Comment: Can you expand on your examples a bit more, please? What exactly is the underlying logic here?

Comment: the number in each string belongs to one group i.e 'a1','b1' and 'c1'. Similarly 'b3','c3','d3',......

Comment: Do you guarantee they are always two-letter codes? Or string of any length?

Comment: The number of elements would be the same for each group and in `Cell_out` each group elements would have their own rows?

Comment: @kyamagu The string of any length.

Comment: @Divakar yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1: Consistent sizes**

```
%%// Input (different from question for a better demo)
Cell_in = {'airplane1','bat1','ball3','cat3','coal1','doggie3'};

ids = cellfun(@(x) x(end), Cell_in,'uni',0) 
[~,ind] = sort(ids)
Cell_out = reshape(Cell_in(ind),[],numel(unique(ids)))' %%// Output
```

**Output**

```
Cell_out = 

    'airplane1'    'bat1'    'coal1'  
    'ball3'        'cat3'    'doggie3'
```

**Case 2: Inconsistent sizes**

```
Cell_in = {'airplane1','bat1','ball3','cat3','coal1','doggie3','cat2','ball2'};

ids = cellfun(@(x) x(end), Cell_in,'uni',0)
unique_ids_num = cellfun(@str2num,unique(ids))
ids_num = cellfun(@str2num,ids)

counts = histc(ids_num,sort(unique_ids_num))

Cell_out = cell(numel(unique_ids_num),max(counts));
for k =1:numel(counts) %%// Maybe accumarray can work here
    Cell_out(k,1:counts(k)) = Cell_in(ids_num==unique_ids_num(k));
end
```

**Output**

```
Cell_out = 

    'airplane1'    'bat1'     'coal1'  
    'cat2'         'ball2'           []
    'ball3'        'cat3'     'doggie3'
```

Comment: I'd use `[unique_ids, ~, index] = unique(regexp(Cell_in, '\d+$', 'match', 'once'))` instead of cellfun.

Comment: @kyamagu Yeah of course that works too! Thanks on that pointer!

Comment: thankyou @kyamagu, Divakar for the valuable answer. Just to extend this thread, what about the output "co" if the input is as follows: Cell_in = {'airplane1','bat1','ball3','cat3','coal1','doggie3','cat2',ball2'}; The code doesn't work in this case. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user3072325 What exactly is `"co"`? Also you agreed to that the number of elements in each group would be the same. In this new input, you have three elements with IDs - 1 and 3 and 2 with ID -2, which is not consistent. So do you want to have like the second group to have one blank cell?

Comment: @Divakar sorry it was a typing mistake I mean Cell_out. Exactly, i would like to have the second group to have one blank cell.

Comment: @user3072325 Check out added **Case 2: Inconsistent sizes**!

Comment: @Divakar one corection: Insidet the for loop  right hand side of the equation ** Cell_in(ids_num==k) ** it should be               ** Cell_in(ids_num==unique_ids_num(k)) **
                                                            **Cell_out(k,1:counts(k)) = Cell_in(ids_num==unique_ids_num(k));**

Answer (score 1):

Using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), as suggested by kyamagu, followed by [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to do the grouping:

```
[~,~,ic] = unique(cell2mat(regexp(Cell_in(:), '\d+$', 'match', 'once')));
[ic,inds] = sort(ic); % to ensure stable ordering of output
co = accumarray(ic,inds,[],@(x){Cell_in(x)});
Cell_out = vertcat(co{:});
```

Comment: Just to extend this thread, what about the output "co" if the input is as follows: Cell_in = {'a1','b1','b3','c3','c1','d3','e2','f2'};  your code doesn't work in this case. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @user3072325 The vertcat fails because the number of elements in each group is not the same (the condition that Divakar verified with you).